# Firemonkey - Combobox highlight item at mouse position

Tags: delphi, combobox, firemonkey, onmouseover

Nearly every application will highlight a comboboxes' item at the current mouse position.

In Firemonkey Embarcadero changed this behavior.

Image1:

[image: Image1]

In this case **ListBoxItem3** should be highlighted - but it isn't.

I then selected **ListBoxItem2** and opened the combobox again.

Image2:

[image: Image2]

ListBoxItem2 keeps being selected even tho ListboxItem4 should be.

As you can see I was using TListBox Items in this example.

In the StyleBook I added a new StyleObject (a blue rectangle) with a TFloatAnimation so i could add a "fake" selection.

But it sadly didn't work.

Image3:

[image: Image3]

So here i am after spending quite some time trying to figure out how to select a comboboxes' item on mouse over movements.

Someone know a way to achieve this?

Comment: If this sounds like a bug I would recommend reporting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a new behaviour introduced by new versions (from X3 onwards), you can set `DropDownKind = ddkCustom` (default value ddkNative) for emulate old behavior.

[image: DropDownKind]

**Note** that using Custom as DropDownKind you obtain a behaviour that it's slightly different from the previous one, since it sets the itemIndex property value immediately, but it shouldn't be a big problem ...

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Chaning to DropDownKind to Custom also made the Stylebook animations work!